# Escape from preventDefault function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, preventdefault

I have code, where on click to `<a>` div shows. It disable my scrollbar and when user click on disable button (img), I wanna escape from my preventDefault function, because when I want use scrollbar, it's again disabled.

As you can see, i give back default css, so website looks like before, but on mousewheel, my scrollbar is again disabled. I'm looking for reset this preventDefault or somehow delete this function, i don't know.

```
$('#region').click(function(e) {
    $('#regions').append("<div class=\"regionWindow\"></div><div class=\"regionCancel\"><img class=\"cancelButton\" src=\"img/cancelButton.png\" /></div>");
    $('.content').css({ "height": "100%", "background": "rgba(0,0,0,0.7)", "pointer-events": "none" });
    $('body').on({
        'mousewheel': function(e) {
            if (e.target.id == 'el') return;
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            $(this).css({ "overflow-y": "scroll", "position": "fixed", "width": "100%" });
        }
    });
    $('.cancelButton').click(function(){
        $('.content').css({"height":"","background":"","pointer-events":""});
        $('#regions').remove('div');
        $('body').css({"overflow-y":"","position":"","width":""});
});
});
```

Comment: Toggle a class on body element instead and set relevant CSS rule in stylesheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to define your event handler as a separate (named) function:

```
function myMouseWheelHandler(e) {
    if (e.target.id == 'el') return;
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).css({ "overflow-y": "scroll", "position": "fixed", "width": "100%" });
};
```

Then keep the `.on()` you have, but now with your named function:

```
$('body').on('mousewheel', myMouseWheelHandler);
```

And then you can remove it with `.off()`:

```
$('body').off('mousewheel', myMouseWheelHandler);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know that .off function exists. Really thank you